# First piece of code in scientific papers

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, history, pseudocode

What is the first/oldest piece of source code shown in an scientific paper or journal? I am looking  for source code of assembly or a high level programming language which was real (implemented) and relevant.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages) says the first high level language would be Plankalkül, which was never implemented. Which leaves us in the 1950ties, maybe something in [J. ACM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_the_ACM) or PHD/research papers?

Comment: Sounds more appropriate for [hsm.se].

Comment: "which was real (implemented) and relevant" seems vague. Does "which had been been run by an actual machine at the time of publication" better describe your intention?

Comment: Lambda-calculus is one of the most relevant programming languages (it underlies all Lisps, most functional languages, a large chunk of type systems) and has been implemented. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, Plankalkül *was* implemented at least three times in 1975, 1998, and 2000).